# Rails 4 : Current user can only edit their post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

User is only able to edit when they are logged in but the problem is any user logged in can edit other users content. How to make user specific edit, only the current user can only edit their content?

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!,except:[:index]

    def show
    end

    def update
        if @job.update(jobs_params)
            redirect_to @job
        else
            render "Edit"
        end
    end 

    private

    def jobs_params
        params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description, :company, :url, :jobcategory_id)
    end

    def find_job
        @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    end
end


show.html.haml                                            
- if user_signed_in?
    = link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"
    = link_to "Edit", edit_job_path(@job), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"
```

Comment: Please now check my final updated answer with full functionality as per your requirement. If it helps you then you can mark as accepted answer. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have not associate `Job` with `User`. without it how you can identify which `Job` is posted by which `User`?

For that associate `Job` with `User`

in **user.rb**

```
has_many :jobs
```

in **job.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

then add `user_id` column to `Job` table and also add `user_id` in your strong parameter.

To add `user_id` column in your `Job` table:

```
rails g migration AddUseridToJob user_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

In your template: **jobs/_form.html.haml** assign `user_id`

```
=  f.hidden_field :user_id , :value => current_user.id
```

by this when user create the `job` in data it will be associated with that particular `User` So you can identify and restrict some actions.

After follow the above steps Try this:

```
- if (user_signed_in? && (current_user.id == @job.user_id))
    = link_to "Edit", edit_job_path(@job), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default"
```

**Note:**

- First Create new Job after sign_in and then check that `edit` action link will be not seen to any other user.
- If you try to check for existing job(old jobs) then you may get an error as existing job's data may not contain user_id
- This will only hides the links of edit.
- You can use [cancancan gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) for authorization

---

If you do not want to allow anyother user to `edit`/`update`/`delete` job and redirect them to index page then implement `job_owner` method like this:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :job_owner]
    before_action :authenticate_user!,except:[:index]
    before_action :job_owner, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
    ....
    # add this method                         
    def job_owner
     unless @job.user_id == current_user.id
      flash[:notice] = 'Access denied as you are not owner of this Job'
      redirect_to jobs_path
     end
    end
    ....                                        
end
```

Comment: I am getting a error undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Yes you will bcz you have not associate `job` with `user`

Comment: class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end

Comment: @akhilranjith : You have not added `user_id` column to Job table.

Comment: As with most of the other answers, your code only hides the link. It doesn't prevent editing someone else's information.

Comment: @Gagan Gami : Thank for trying to help me out .. i am new to rails ... I am using Devise ,it had created user.rb in models, now how should i add used_id  to job table ?

Comment: @akhilranjith : I have updated my answer how you can add `user_id` in `Job` table

Comment: @Mischa : Now please check I have update my answer which will not allowed other user to perform any job modification or job delete action .

Comment: @akhilranjith : I have updated my answer which will not only hide links but not even let other user to perform edit/update/delete action. If this help you then you can mark as answered. I suggest you also have a look at `cancancan gem`

Comment: @Gagan Gami : Thanks for your answer it worked, but when a user creates a new job the user_id is not getting linked with it, anyway i have found the method to solve that also using build in def new & create .

Comment: @akhilranjith : Glad to help you. Have you added `user_id` in job_params(strong parameter) ?

Comment: @GaganGami : Ho i didn't add user_id in job_params.... know i understand my mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use [cancancan gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) and define your ability as below:

```
 can [ :edit, :update, :delete ], Job do |job|
   job.user_id == user.id
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper method:

```
def user_allowed
  user_signed_in? && (current_user.id == @job.user_id)
end
```

And then call it before your actions:

```
<% if user_allowed %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this?

```
= link_to "Edit", edit_job_path(@job), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default" if @current_user.id == @job.owner_id
```

Note that owner_id is something I made up. You haven't given enough context around what a user can/can't edit. How do you determine if a job belongs to a user or is editable by them. That should give you something to go on though.

You probably want to investigate some sort of authorization gem like [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit). Pundit will allow you to setup policies per controller and allow you to manage access with fine granularity. The documentation describes how to set it up and use before_action's to validate authorization prior to the action being run.

Comment: Might be better to set up a `before_action` in the controller and then use it to restrict particular actions (like edit).  Adding logic like this to the view is not a great idea.

Comment: It only hides the link, but doesn't restrict anything! You can still edit someone else's job.

Comment: Yes, that is why I suggested pundit.

Comment: I have added a before_action in the controller

Comment: Cool, but you should really check out pundit. It's widely used and much more extensible, maintainable and testable.

Comment: The point is that your first suggestion is wrong. It doesn't prevent anything.

Comment: @steveklein : as per your comment I have updated my answer. Thanks for your this point :)